PJSIP/PJSUA Cancel call in Early state
I'm trying to create sip dialler using PJSIP in Python. All is working fine, but I want to be able to hang up call after certain amount of seconds when it's not answered/while it's still in early state.
I have this part of code doing that, it reaches it but it seams call. Hangup () doesn't work as I want in def cancel_call (call).
Can you help me determine why CANCEL is not sent?
import pjsua as pj
import threading
import time

# Define a callback class for logging and events
class MyCallCallback(pj.CallCallback):
    def __init__(self, call=None, cancel_timer=None):
        pj.CallCallback.__init__(self, call)
        self.cancel_timer = cancel_timer

    def on_state(self):
        current_state = self.call.info().state
        print("Call is", self.call.info().state_text, "last code =", self.call.info().last_code, "(" + self.call.info().last_reason + ")")

        # Handle confirmed (answered) call
        if current_state == pj.CallState.CONFIRMED:
            print("Call is answered.")
            self.cancel_timer.cancel()  # Cancel the timeout since the call is answered
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Hanging up the call 1 second after it was answered.")
            try:
                self.call.hangup()  # Hang up the call after it was answered
                print("Call has been hung up after being answered.")
            except pj.Error as e:
                print(f"Error during hangup after answer: {e}")

        # Handle disconnected call
        elif current_state == pj.CallState.DISCONNECTED:
            print("Call is disconnected.")
            if self.cancel_timer:
                self.cancel_timer.cancel()  # Ensure the timer is canceled if the call is disconnected

    def on_media_state(self):
        pass  # No media handling needed since RTP is disabled

def cancel_call(call):
    print("No answer within 8 seconds, sending CANCEL (487 Request Terminated).")
    try:
        call.hangup()  # Send a CANCEL
        print("CANCEL request (487 Request Terminated) has been sent.")
    except pj.Error as e:
        print(f"Error during cancel: {e}")

# Initialize the PJSUA library
lib = pj.Lib()

# Initialize the library with default configuration and logging
lib.init(log_cfg=pj.LogConfig(level=5))

# List all available codecs and disable all except PCMU and PCMA
codec_info = lib.enum_codecs()
for codec in codec_info:
    if codec.name not in ["PCMU/8000/1", "PCMA/8000/1"]:
        lib.set_codec_priority(codec.name, 0)  # Disable codec
    else:
        lib.set_codec_priority(codec.name, 255)  # Enable codec with highest priority

# Create UDP transport
transport = lib.create_transport(pj.TransportType.UDP)

# Start the library
lib.start()

# Set the null sound device as we do not handle media
lib.set_null_snd_dev()

# Account configuration
acc_cfg = pj.AccountConfig()
acc_cfg.id = "sip:48123456789@1.1.1.1"
acc_cfg.reg_uri = "sip:1.1.1."

# Create the account
acc = lib.create_account(acc_cfg)

# Make the call with the custom callback
call = acc.make_call("sip:489876543214@1.1.1.1", MyCallCallback())

# Set up a timer to cancel the call if it's not answered within 8 seconds
cancel_timer = threading.Timer(8, cancel_call, [call])
cancel_timer.start()

# Pass the cancel_timer to the callback so it can be canceled if the call is answered
call._cb = MyCallCallback(call, cancel_timer)

# Keep the application running
try:
    while True:
        lib.handle_events(100)  # Handle SIP events in 100ms intervals
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Interrupted by user")

# Clean up when done
lib.destroy()

